# How can i delete user images/avatar in user profile

Tags: python, django

if there's anyone who knows how can I delete images user, I made a code to do that but I cannot continue I get some stuck. so if anyone could tell me which way can I make it this method?
also, I need to know about the outputs of (userprofile) in (delete_avatar) if this code is true how can I know it? I tried using print and repr but I didn't find this useful.  so, anybody can get me help?

views.py

```
# Update Avatar
@login_required
def add_avatar(request, user_id):
    my_logo = request.user.userprofile
    form = AddAvatar(instance=my_logo)
    get_userid = UserProfile.objects.filter(user_id=user_id)
    context = {'form': form, 'get_userid': get_userid}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddAvatar(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=my_logo)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('account:view_profile')

    return render(request, 'account/change-image.html', context)


# Remove Avatar
@login_required
def delete_avatar(request, user_id):
    my_request = request.POST.get('rm-img')
    userprofile = UserProfile(my_request)

    pdb.set_trace()
    if request.method == "POST":
        del_img = UserProfile.objects.get(user_id=user_id).logo.delete() # delete object
        return redirect('account:view_profile')
    return render(request, 'account/change-image.html')
```

change-image.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %} Add New Image {% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<!-- Add new image for user-profile -->
<div class="change-image">
    <div class="add-image">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>This Image Is Current, <br>Choose Your Image From Your Personal Computer Or Delete</h1>
            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <label>{{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</label>
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Change Now</button>
                <input type="submit" name="rm-img" class="btn btn-danger" value="Remove Image">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

the file html above where I can make a form to update and delete the user image

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('new-image/<int:user_id>/', views.add_avatar, name="add_avatar"),
    path('del-image/', views.delete_avatar, name="delete_avatar"),
]
```

forms.py

```
class AddAvatar(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['logo']
```

Comment: find image path attached to the user profile and delete it with `os`

Comment: how can I do that by request.POST? I have two inputs to make submit to the form the first is for changing the image and the last is to remove the image user so how can i remove the image by this button

Comment: just in you view.py create function that will search database for that user , get image path ,then delete it

Comment: I understand what you need to say but I cannot do that because what i told you before I have two button submit in the same form. if you could explain that in detail, please?

Comment: where you need to delete image? after button click, after form submit? If in form you have multiple buttons then give one button submit function and for the rest create simple buttons that will interact with ajax